# Understanding coin change recursion

Tags: java, recursion, coin-change

I was trying to solve the coin change problem specifically using **recursion**, and came across the below code.

**Problem:** Given infinite coins of some denominations, calculate the no. of ways the given amount can be formed by them.

Input:

```
int[] coins = {1, 2}; 
int amount = 5;
int ways = change(amount, coins, coins.length - 1);
// expected ways = 3 --> 11111, 1112, 122
```

Code:

```
int change(int amount, int[] coins, int index) {
    if (amount < 0) return 0;
    if (amount == 0) return 1;
    
    int ways = 0;
    while (amount > 0 && index >= 0) {
        ways += change(amount - coins[index], coins, index);
        index = index - 1;
    }
    return ways;
}
```

I understand the code itself and I understand the base cases as well, but I am failing to understand how it encapsulates the recursion/solution.

Eg. If I am solving the `factorial(n)`, I can say that `factorial(n) = n * factorial(n-1)`, so I can clearly "see" the recursion. I am not able to deduce a similar relation in the coin change example. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Part of calculating the number of ways of making say 50 monetary units is saying "If I use a 10 unit coin, then I am left with having to make up the remaining 40 units: how many ways is that?". That's the recursive relationship.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to get to! Can you please elaborate a bit? So if I want `5` from `{2, 1}`, what do I need to add to the solution of getting `3` from `{2, 1}`? Basically in the factorial recursion I had to multiply n to the previous solution. Whats the corresponding concept here?

Comment: To make 5 from 2s and 1s, you can start with a 2, then there are so many ways of making the remaining 3; or you can start with a 1, then there are so many ways of making the remaining 4. Those two options in combination give you the number of ways of making 5.

Comment: thank you! Still not 100% clear, but I will spend some time on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recursive line is here: `ways += change(amount - coins[index], coins, index);`

I've commented the code to explain it a bit.

```java
//amount is the total value we want all our coins to add up to
//coins carries the values we can add up to get the amount
//index is the coin we're "on" right now - we'll explain this more in a bit
int change(int amount, int[] coins, int index) {

    //we went too low: out last coin was too large and pushed us into negatives
    if (amount < 0) return 0;
    //exact change! we found a new way to make change with these coins
    if (amount == 0) return 1;
    
    //count the number of ways we can make the change
    int ways = 0;

    //here's where the recursion starts: we start at index, which is the number of
    //coins available to us. in this case, we're going right to the end of the
    //array to the "2" coin. we'll repeatedly subtract "2" from the amount until
    //we hit 0, meaning we were able to meet the amount using only "2" coins, or
    //we're unable to go any further.
    //if we're unable to go further, we return one level up from the recursion,
    //and decrease index by 1: this means we're now trying the "1" coin. 
    //this process repeats, making as much change with the "2" coin as we can and
    //falling back to the "1" coin when we get stuck or reach the bottom of the
    //recursion.
    while (amount > 0 && index >= 0) {
        //try to use this same coin over and over, and when the function returns,
        //whether through success or failure...
        ways += change(amount - coins[index], coins, index);
        //...move onto the next coin and repeat the process.
        index = index - 1;
    }
 
    //the total number of times we were able to make exact change with these coins
    return ways;
}
```

In plainer terms:

```
desired value: 5    available coins: 1, 2
value = 5
coin = 2
5 - 2 = 3

. value = 3
. coin = 2
. 3 - 2 = 1

. . value = 1
. . coin = 2
. . 1 - 2 = -1 | fail
. . coin = 1
. . 1 - 1 = 0 | success
. . no more coins to try

. value = 3
. coin = 1
. 3 - 1 = 2

. . value = 2
. . coin = 1
. . 2 - 1 = 1

. . . value = 1
. . . coin = 1
. . . 1 - 1 = 0 | success
. . . no more coins to try

. . no more coins to try

. no more coins to try

value = 5
coin = 1
5 - 1 = 4

. value = 4
[...and so on]
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer and write the comments, and I complete understand the code, but trying to understand the recursion i.e. how I can get the current solution from the previous solutions.

Comment: @Ufder the easiest way: take a paper and a pen, and draw the code's path: forward and backward at each return. When you reach back to the start point, it will make sense

Comment: @Ufder I've added a visual explanation.

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort! Perhaps I didn't word my question clearly. Basically if I take the above code and work through the recursion, I am able to see whats happening. What I am trying to understand is without having this code in front of me, how can I write the recursion i.e. solution to the current problem in terms of its sub problems. I'll spend some more time on it, and go through the answers here and once it clicks, I'll accept. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ufder "Select the biggest coin and subtract it from the total amount as many times as you can. If you hit a negative, undo the last subtract, select the next smallest coin, and keep trying. If you hit 0, that counts as a success - record it, then undo the subtracts until you get to the previous coin you were using. Change it to the current coin, then repeat. Do this until you've tested every coin." (Note that for the sake of explanation, the coins are sorted by size in this example, but you don't need them to be sorted for the algorithm to work.)

Comment: That makes sense! Though how does it avoid repetitions i.e. `2 + 2 + 1` vs `1 + 2 + 2` as both are essentially the same combination.

Comment: The index is passed into the recursive call, keeping its place in the coon array; it does not reset to the end abd does not repeat previous coins. If the index is at the "1" coin, the algorithm never goes back to "2", even after the recursion returns.

Comment: @NickReed Dude, all those youtube videos where they were saying `Pick a coin vs Discard a coin` and I couldn't understand and yet once I see your comment and I understood right away. Thank you !!